# Firebase-auth Error with Facebook

Tags: facebook, firebase, polymer, firebase-authentication, facebook-login

Firebase auth with Facebook just stopped working on all our Polymer websites. One of them where updated 19th of march and has been working until yesterday/this afternoon (2017-03-27).

I get the following error message in chrome:

```
firebase-auth.js:32

"{"error":{"errors":[{"domain":"global","reason":"invalid","message":"A system error has occurred"}],"code":400,"message":"A system error has occurred"}}
```

Comment: Same issue here, started today.Good to know it's not an issue with our application.

Comment: Still trying to root cause this. Caused by an update at Facebook but we’re unsure where the breakage is. Tracking it here: https://status.firebase.google.com/incident/Authentication/17001

Comment: Although i m using firebase for authentication .. was getting the same error.. than upgraded FB SDK and it worked fine.. chk this code https://github.com/packetcode/Facebook-login-php-sdk-v5

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firebase Authentication is having problems right now. Look at the Firebase Status Dashboard here:
https://status.firebase.google.com/

Answer (score 3):

Graph API v2.2 has reached the end of its 2-year lifetime on 27 March, 2017, so this might be connected. You should check your library and possible updates. See [this chart of deprecation dates](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog#versions), which lists v2.2 as available until March 25, 2017.

Comment: I suggest improving this answer by providing a link to any official documentation or announcement mentioning the end of life.