# Firebase Facebook Login suddenly broke by itself?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-login

I have two web apps that rely on login with Facebook in Firebase. Everything was working perfectly for weeks and now both logins stopped working.
I only get "code":400, "message":"A system error has occured" and below - "HTTP400: BAD REQUEST - The request could not be processed by the server due to invalid syntax" pointing to www.googleapis.com/identitytoolkit/v3/relyingparty/verifyAssertion?key={MY_FIREBASE_API_KEY}

This is the part of code that's initiating login if that matters:

```
firebase.auth().signInWithPopup(FBprovider).then((result) => {
  let user = firebase.auth().currentUser;
  dispatch(login());
  console.log(result);
  browserHistory.push('review');
 }, (e) => console.log(e));
```

Please, do let me know what is that and how can I fix it. I plan to release my apps soon and such sudden issues that completely break them out of nowhere is way too scary...

Comment: https://status.firebase.google.com/incident/Authentication/17001

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Firebase-auth Error with Facebook](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43054813/firebase-auth-error-with-facebook)

Comment: Flagging to consolidate issue to a single post.