# Ionic - Firebase Facebook Login - A system error has occurred

Tags: firebase, ionic2, firebase-authentication

I'm utilizing Firebase Facebook login for an application that I'm building and it had been working flawlessly up until a few hours ago. Now when I try to use the Firebase Facebook login, I get this error:

```
cordovaWarn @ main.js:4888
https://www.googleapis.com/identitytoolkit/v3/relyingparty/verifyAssertion?key=AIzaSyAVc6kX8cG5IvvHZE8-7lORJOH8HItyPBU Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 400 ()
main.js:65862 EXCEPTION: Uncaught (in promise): Error: {"error":{"errors":[{"domain":"global","reason":"invalid","message":"A system error has occurred"}],"code":400,"message":"A system error has occurred"}}
ErrorHandler.handleError @ main.js:65862
main.js:65867 ORIGINAL STACKTRACE:
ErrorHandler.handleError @ main.js:65867
main.js:65868 Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: {"error":{"errors":[{"domain":"global","reason":"invalid","message":"A system error has occurred"}],"code":400,"message":"A system error has occurred"}}
    at s (polyfills.js:3)
    at s (polyfills.js:3)
    at polyfills.js:3
    at t.invokeTask (polyfills.js:3)
    at Object.onInvokeTask (main.js:48660)
    at t.invokeTask (polyfills.js:3)
    at e.runTask (polyfills.js:3)
    at i (polyfills.js:3)
    at invoke (polyfills.js:3)
```

Does anyone have any idea what could be causing this?

Comment: Seems to be widespread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43054813/firebase-auth-error-with-facebook

Comment: https://status.firebase.google.com/incident/Authentication/17001

Comment: Oh thankyou for that! Here I was going crazy thinking it was me haha

Comment: Although i m using firebase for authentication .. was getting the same error.. than upgraded FB SDK and it worked fine.. chk this code https://github.com/packetcode/Facebook-login-php-sdk-v5